Cypress test visits routes before login completes when using loop in GitHub Actions
I'm writing Cypress tests for my web application and encountered an issue where my test starts visiting restricted pages before the login process is complete when using a loop. However, if I remove the loop and test each page one by one, everything works fine. This issue only occurs when running the tests in GitHub Actions.
Here is my test code:
describe('when prices only client tries to access restricted pages.', () => {
    const restrictedPages = [
        '/',
        '/trade-flows',
        '/vessel-tracking',
        '/port-analytics/overview',
        '/container-tracking',
        '/news/overview',
        '/chart-builder/sugar-summaries',
        '/downloads/kulea-balance-sheets',
    ];

    it('should redirect to /prices/commodity-dashboard?groupId=1 if trying to access', () => {
        cy.logIn({ accountType: 'banker', loginDetailsCorrect: true });
        restrictedPages.forEach((page) => {
            cy.wait(100);
            cy.visit(page);

            cy.location('pathname', { timeout: 10000 }).should('equal', '/prices/commodity-dashboard');
        });
    });
});

Why does the loop cause the test to visit the routes before the login process completes, and how can I fix it?
The cy.logIn function is a custom command that handles the login process.
The application redirects to /prices/commodity-dashboard?groupId=1 for unauthorized access to restricted pages.
The issue only occurs when using a loop to iterate through the restricted pages.

You may have better luck using the cy.session() to perform the login.
Without being able to run the test, it's hard to be sure, but I am thinking that cy.visit() may be clearing the data that is provided by the login.
This is the pattern I would used, based on your current test
describe('when prices only client...', () => {

  // using a session pattern to keep the login data fresh for each page visit
  beforEach(() => {
    cy.session('login', () => {
      cy.logIn({ accountType: 'banker', loginDetailsCorrect: true })
    })
  })

  const restrictedPages = [
    '/',
    ... etc
  ]

  restrictedPages.forEach((page) => {

    // make each redirect a separate test to invoke the session code above
    it(`test redirect for ${page}`, () => {
      cy.visit(page);
      cy.location('pathname', { timeout: 10000 })
        .should('equal', '/prices/commodity-dashboard');
    })
  })
})

Note with cy.session() the login only happens once, but the login data is preserved and restored between tests (see cy.session() documentation)
Overall, this should give you cleaner separation between those page visits, but at the cost of more test entries (one per path) in the results.

Visiting before login is complete
The above code only performs one login, but the original issue should be solvable by adding an assertion after the cy.login() command.
For example, if the user name is displayed on the page after logging in, make an assertion that the name is visible
cy.logIn({ accountType: 'banker', loginDetailsCorrect: true });

// confirm something on the page that only shows after login has finished
cy.get('span#username').should('contain', 'the-name-of-the-user');

cy.visit(page)  // this won't start until above assertion has passed 

